# A non constant analytic function is open

Tags: analytic-functions, open-map

I recently came across the following theorem.

> **Theorem**
>
> Let $f\colon U\to \mathbb K$ be a non constant analytic function, where $U$ is an open connected space of $\mathbb K=\mathbb R\text{ or }\mathbb C$.
>
> Then $f$ is an open map (*i.e.* is $V$ is open, then $f(V)$ is open).

I was wondering about a counterexample if $f$ is only $C^\infty$, but I was not able to find one. Do you have one ?

Comment: Actually, the theorem cannot be right. Take $\sin(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You're right, I tought it would be also true on $\mathbb R$, but turns out it is only true for holomorphic functions.

Comment: I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: $e^{-x^2}$ is analytic on $\mathbb{R}$ but its image is $(0,1]$. For a complex analytic function on $U \subset \mathbb{C}$, the proof of the open mapping is by supposing $a \in U, f(a) \in \partial f(U)$ and using that $f(a+z) = f(a)+C z^n+ o(|z|^n)$ for some $C \ne 0$ (since $f$ is non-constant), a contradiction since $f(B_\epsilon(a))$ contains an open ball around $f(a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the complex case, the theorem is called the open mapping theorem. The Theorem is actually false for $\mathbb{R}$, as the example $\sin(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}$ shows. ($\sin[(0,4\pi)] = [-1,1]$.) One could also consider the function $f(x) = x^2$ which maps $(-1,1)$ to $[0,1)$.

The original counterexample loses some interest, but I will keep it here for the sake of keeping the record: A counterexample over $\mathbb{R}$ is the bump map, i.e., $f(x) = e^{-1/(1-|x|^2)}$ for $|x|<1$ and $f(x)=0$ for $|x|\geq 1$. Then $f$ is $C^\infty$, but $f[(-2,2)] = [0,e^{-1}]$ is closed.

The idea here is that the bump map interpolates smoothly between the constant function $0$ to the left and right of $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Thanks, though I think you meant $\vert x\vert ^2$ in your function, otherwise it is not $C^\infty$.

Comment: Absolutely, thanks! Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 2):

In the complex case, any real valued function is a counterexample, e.g. $f(z)=|z|^2$.